# Как отсортировать json массив относительно 2 поля

Tags: php, ajax, массивы, json

Сортировка по базам не нужна. Использование плагинов ни к чему хорошему не привело - таблица косая получилась.
Дан массив. Я формирую его в `php`.

```
$row_section['cell'][$index] = array(
    0,
    $tovar,
    $cnt,
    $productID,
    $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["VALUE"],
    $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["BREND"]["VALUE"],
    $arElement["NAME"],
    $n,
    $arElement["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_DAYS_DELIVERY"]["VALUE"],
    $price
);
$index=$index+1;

$mas=json_encode($row_section,256);
```

Я отправляю на сервер нажатием на заголовок таблицы:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="def-table-code">
            <a href="<?=$url?>&sort=property_CML2_ARTICLE&method=<?=$method?>">Код</a>
        </th>

        <th class="def-table-manufacturer">
            <a href="<?=$url?>&sort=property_BREND&method=<?=$method?>">Производитель</a>
        </th>

        <th class="def-table-title">
            <a href="<?=$url?>&sort=NAME&method=<?=$method?>">Название</a>
        </th>

        <!-- 
            <th class="def-table-available">
                <a href="<?=$url?>&sort=CATALOG_QUANTITY&method=<?=$method?>">Количество, шт.</a>
            </th>

            <th class="def-table-delivery">
                <a href="<?=$url?>&sort=property_CML2_DAYS_DELIVERY&method=<?=$method?>">Срок поставки, дн.
            </th>

            <th class="def-table-price">Цена, руб.</th>
            <th class="def-table-buy">В корзину</th>
        -->

        <th class="def-table-available sort_id" id="CATALOG_QUANTITY" onclick="cat(5,1);">Количество, шт.</th>

        <th class="def-table-delivery sort_id" id="property_CML2_DAYS_DELIVERY" onclick="cat(6,1);">Срок поставки, дн.</th>

        <th class="def-table-price sort_id" id="CATALOG_PRICE" onclick="cat(7,1);">Цена, руб.</th>

        <th class="def-table-buy">В корзину</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Отправляю `ajax` запросом  на сервер:

```
function cat(sortby, method){
    alert(sortby);
    alert(method);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/unimann/ajax/sortfromcatalogajax.php?sortby='+sortby+'&method='+method
        type: 'POST',
        data: massiv,
        success: function(res) {
            $('#sort_tab').html(res);
            alert('Soxranenp!');
        }
    });
}
```

На сервере я планирую:

```
$data=  json_decode($_POST['massiv'],true);
```

Получится массив (на сервере не удалось проверить, не знаю, отправилось ли). 
По идее должен получиться такой массив

```
Array ( [cell] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 453852 [2] => TB215363 [3] => FENOX [4] => TB215363_диск тормозной передний!\ Audi 80/90/100 1.6-2.0D 86-91 [5] => 6 [6] => 1 [7] => 772.52 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 355471 [2] => 8DD 355 100-581 [3] => HELLA [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент. [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 1044.41 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 228617 [2] => 0986478016 [3] => BOSCH [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1. [5] => 6 [6] => 1 [7] => 1126.23 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 440468 [2] => 0986478016 [3] => BOSCH [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1. [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 1126.23 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 228618 [2] => 0986478016 [3] => BOSCH [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1. [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 1126.23 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 140741 [2] => BG2215 [3] => DELPHI [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент. [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 876.12 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 128269 [2] => A1081P [3] => LPR [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент. [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 1046.65 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 184737 [2] => 24.0113-0160.1 [3] => ATE [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo [5] => 4 [6] => 2 [7] => 1216.57 ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 315459 [2] => 24.0113-0160.1 [3] => ATE [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo [5] => 10 [6] => 1 [7] => 1216.57 ) ) )
```

Вопрос: как отсортировать либо по полю `cell[][5]`, либо `cell[][6]`, либо `cell[][7]` относительно `cell[][0]` и `cell[][1]`? То есть, сравниваем элементы, у которых `cell[][1]` одинаковое, и сортируем по возрастанию или убыванию.

Нужно отсортировать в пределах объединения. В табличке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы понимаете, что Ваша постановка проблемы уж слишком сложна и длинна? Упростите Ваш вопрос, а то в итоге его даже никто до конца не прочитает.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая функция — **[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)** .

```
$babbie = Array ( "cell" => Array ( 
        "0" =>  Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 453852, 
            "2" => "TB215363", 
            "3" => "FENOX",
            "4" => "TB215363_диск тормозной передний!\ Audi 80/90/100 1.6-2.0D 86-91",
            "5" => 6,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 772.52), 
        "1" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 355471, 
            "2" => "DD 355 100-581", 
            "3" => "HELLA",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.",
            "5" => 2, 
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1044.41 ), 
        "2" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 228617,
            "2" => "0986478016", 
            "3" => "BOSCH",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.",
            "5" => 6,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1126.23 ), 
        "3" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 440468, 
            "2" => "0986478016", 
            "3" => "BOSCH", 
            "4" => "Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.",
            "5" => 2,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1126.23 ), 
        "4" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 228618, 
            "2" => "0986478016", 
            "3" => "BOSCH",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.",
            "5" => 2,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1126.23 ), 
        "5" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 140741, 
            "2" => "BG2215",
            "3" => "DELPHI",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.", 
            "5" => 2,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 876.12 ), 
        "6" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 128269,
            "2" => "A1081P",
            "3" => "LPR",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.",
            "5" => 2,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1046.65 ), 
        "7" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 184737,
            "2" => "24.0113-0160.1",
            "3" => "ATE",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo",
            "5" => 4,
            "6" => 2,
            "7" => 1216.57 ), 
        "8" => Array ( 
            "0" => 1,
            "1" => 315459,
            "2" => "24.0113-0160.1", 
            "3" => "ATE",
            "4" => "Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo",
            "5" => 10,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1216.57 ) ) );

print("<pre>"); print_r($babbie); print("</pre>");
// Получение списка столбцов массива $babie["cell"]
foreach ($babbie["cell"] as $key => $row) {
    $col_0[$key] = $row[0];
    $col_1[$key] = $row[1];
}
// Сортируем данные по col_0 по col_1 по возрастанию
// Добавляем $babbie["cell"] в качестве последнего параметра, для сортировки по общему ключу
array_multisort($col_0, SORT_ASC, $col_1, SORT_ASC, $babbie["cell"]);
print("<pre>"); print_r($babbie); print("</pre>");
```

Результаты:

```
Array
(
    [cell] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 453852
                    [2] => TB215363
                    [3] => FENOX
                    [4] => TB215363_диск тормозной передний!\ Audi 80/90/100 1.6-2.0D 86-91
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 772.52
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 355471
                    [2] => DD 355 100-581
                    [3] => HELLA
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1044.41
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 228617
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 440468
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 228618
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 140741
                    [2] => BG2215
                    [3] => DELPHI
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 876.12
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 128269
                    [2] => A1081P
                    [3] => LPR
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1046.65
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 184737
                    [2] => 24.0113-0160.1
                    [3] => ATE
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 2
                    [7] => 1216.57
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 315459
                    [2] => 24.0113-0160.1
                    [3] => ATE
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo
                    [5] => 10
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1216.57
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [cell] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 128269
                    [2] => A1081P
                    [3] => LPR
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1046.65
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 140741
                    [2] => BG2215
                    [3] => DELPHI
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 876.12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 184737
                    [2] => 24.0113-0160.1
                    [3] => ATE
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 2
                    [7] => 1216.57
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 228617
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 228618
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 315459
                    [2] => 24.0113-0160.1
                    [3] => ATE
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн, AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9/2.0 D/2.0 D Turbo
                    [5] => 10
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1216.57
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 355471
                    [2] => DD 355 100-581
                    [3] => HELLA
                    [4] => Диск тормозной AUDI 80 86>91/100 76>88 передний не вент.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1044.41
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 440468
                    [2] => 0986478016
                    [3] => BOSCH
                    [4] => Диск тормозной передн AUDI: 100 1.6/1.9/2.0 D/2.1 76-82, 100 1.8/1.8 KAT/1.9 82-91, 100 Avant 1.6/1.
                    [5] => 2
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 1126.23
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 453852
                    [2] => TB215363
                    [3] => FENOX
                    [4] => TB215363_диск тормозной передний!\ Audi 80/90/100 1.6-2.0D 86-91
                    [5] => 6
                    [6] => 1
                    [7] => 772.52
                )

        )

)
```

А дальше читайте документацию.